# How do I find out if wifi card supports 4addr mode?

Tags: centos, networking, wifi, dhcp

I want to setup a wireless network, with some wired devices plugged to wireless clients. All of them should have same IP pool / same subnet from DHCP server.

One approach is probably the configuration of wireless DHCP server and wireless clients in 4addr mode, if available.

How do I find out if my preferred wireless card (on both server and clients) supports this mode ? May `iw list` be helpful ? You'll find it [here as output text](https://ssl.ddpos.de/iw_list.txt)

Intel WiFi 6E ax210 NGFF, mixed vPro and non vPro versions.

More details you'll find [here on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680069/wired-ethernet-device-on-a-wifi-client-computer-using-the-same-subnet-and-ip-fr)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wireless-Wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw#using_4-address_for_ap_and_client_mode) the Wi-FI interface support 4addr mode if  AP or STA modes are supported.

> Linux wireless has support for 4-address mode for AP and STAs but each driver needs to define this capability explicitly. All mac80211 drivers support 4-address mode if AP or STA modes of operation are supported respectively.

To check if AP mode is supported:

```
iw list |grep -A10 "Supported interface modes:"
```

Comment: It seems to work. With AP running and `sudo iw dev wlp2s0 set 4addr on` I get answered `command failed: Operation not supported (-95)`. But after `sudo nmcli connection down Hotspot` it seems to be set. Will continue with further success infos here.